# Do enhancements factor into the advancement xp cost of attributes and skills?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5, shadowrun

If an adept has the power to increase an attribute, which cost is used for the normal increment of the attribute, the attribute's normal value or its increased value?

For example, with Reflexes 3 and Increased Reflexes 3 would the adept pay 20 xp (4 x 5) or 35 xp?

Is this rule identical for permanently enhanced skills?

Comment: Always nice to know why a - or close vote is there ;)

Comment: Normally because you asked multiple questions within the question.

Comment: @ShadowKras originally it was not 2 questions (the skill parts was originally "just" a side comment (as I took the same rules applied to there)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### No, they don't.

*Augmentations* have a lot of rules that work differently and *on top* of your own abilities. One of those is about how you should buy advancements with karma, which state that you use your actual score and pay for the next increase. There is no mention of *augmented scores* at all, because **enhancements are not calculated** there.

> First, when purchasing augmentations such as cyberware and bioware, each attribute rating (Mental and Physical) can only receive an augmentation bonus of up to +4. If the attribute being raised has not reached its natural maximum limit, **the attribute can be raised naturally with Karma**; but at no point can augmentations exceed the +4 bonus cap. (Core book, page 94)

Comment: Superb wasn't sure from the formulation (both the english and german versions of the rules wern't 100% clear on that subject for me)